# How to bind a list of objects from a form in the View to the Controller in Spring 3

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-3

I hope i can explain my self clearly since I'm just starting with Spring.

Say I have the following bean:

```
public class UserAnswer {
    private String answer;

    public UserAnswer() {
    }
    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }
    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }
```

This is a controller method that redirects to my view. Please note the parameters passed to the model

```
@RequestMapping(value="/usuarios/cambiar_estado", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String bloquearDesbloquearUsuario(@RequestParam (value="usuarioPinIdHidden", required=false) String pinId, Model model){
        try{
            List<Question> questionList = servicioAcceso.getSecurityQuestionsByUser(Long.parseLong(pinId));
            model.addAttribute("userAnswer", new UserAnswer());
            model.addAttribute("questionList", questionList);           
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return "login/pregunta_seguridad";              
    }
```

This is the view login/pregunta_seguridad.jsp that renders a list of Questions. I need every element of the list 
to be binded to a list of items of type UserAnswer:

```
<c:url var="url" value="/usuarios/compare_answers"/>
<form:form modelAttribute="userAnswer" action="${url}" method="POST">
    <c:if test="${not empty answerList}">
        <table class="summary" style="border: none;">
            <c:forEach var="question" items="${questionList}">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">${question.description}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <form:input path="answer" id="answer"/> 
                </tr>       
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </c:if>
    <div class="span-3 last">
            <button type="submit">Confirm</button>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

I need a way to get a list of UserAnswer

```
@RequestMapping(value="/usuarios/compare_answers", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String compareAnswer(Model model, UserAnswer userAnswer){
        try{
            //this is where I should receive a list of UserAnswer
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

How could I do something like that in Spring?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a pretty good example: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2011/12/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list.html

Comment: thanks GriffeyDog! The example was very useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think directly you cannot bind a list of objects to your form backing bean, rather you can bind a parent class which contains this list, for example UserForm class contains list of UserAnswer and bind the UserForm as the form backing bean.

Comment: yes, I think that's the right way to do it. It's the same solution recommended in the link posted by GriffeyDog. I'll try it right now!